# Error in "If" statement in R coding

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling, count

This is my code:

```
#Start of my Code#
test1<-function(c,x){
high=0
low=0
samp=NULL

samp=sample(c,x)
for(i in 1:x){
if(samp[i]>1){high=high+1}
else if (samp[i]<0){low=low+1}}
c(high,low,mean(samp),var(samp),samp)
}

sim1 <-function(c,x){
replicate(nsim,{test1(c,x)})}

size=10
a<-sim1(overall,size)

listnormwor=NULL
countnormwor=0
meannormwor=NULL

for(i in 0:nsim-1){
**if (a[1+(size+4)*i]+a[2+(size+4)*i]==0)**{ 
countnormwor=countnormwor +1
for (z in 5:(size+4)){ 
listnormwor=c(listnormwor, a[z+(size+4)*i])}
meannormwor=c(meannormwor,a[3+(size+4)*i])}
}

countnormwor
mean(meannormwor)
var(listnormwor)
```

Simply, I want to say if there are no outliers (indicated as '0' in first and second value of every 14 data points), count it into a normal bucket and keep its values to calculate variance and mean later.

But the problem is that, it generates all values from a and at the very end, it provides actual values I want.

For example, it must satisfy length(listnormwor) = 10 * countnormwor

But it gives me a ridiculous amount of data and when I play around with the if statement, it says "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed."

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest stepping through the code (sending each line to the interpreter) one line at a time. Inspect the value of variables by calling them in the interpreter. I bet this will lead you to the source of your problem. To start, create the values `x` and `c` inside the function then work from there. Instead of running the `for` loop, create your own index variable `i`. Again, the point is to work line by line and carefully check your expectations against the values that variables take at each point.